# Diff says file does not exists – why?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-scripting

I transfer a file from a remote server to my local server. If this is done I do a diff to check if both files are identical to check if the transfer was successful. So I do this:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${SSH_USER} ${SSH_HOST} "cat $FOLDERPATH_REMOTE.tar.gz" | diff - "$FOLDERPATH_LOCAL.tar.gz"
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "\n##### Remove file from remote machine #####\n"
        rm -f $FOLDERPATH_REMOTE.tar.gz
    fi
```

When I do this, I get always an error like this:

`diff: /home/backups/test.tar.gz: No such file or directory`

and

`[[: not found`

But when I do a `cat /home/backups/test.tar.gz` the file exists. So somehow the command does not distinguish between local and remote system and the if after the ssh command is not executing.

Does anybody knows what I am doing wrong?

P.S: And another beginner question: When do I have to write variables like this `${VAR}` and when like `$VAR`?

Comment: `[[` is a `bash` syntax, but you seem to be running under a different shell.

Comment: I also tried it with:

`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -l ${SSH_USER} ${SSH_HOST} "cat $FOLDERPATH_REMOTE.tar.gz" | diff - "$FOLDERPATH_LOCAL.tar.gz" /bin/bash << EOF
 if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
     rm -f $FOLDERPATH_REMOTE$FILEPREFIX-$DATETIME.tar.gz
 fi
EOF`
But even then I get a No such file or directory error, as the script does not to understand that it should compare on two different systems.

Comment: Don't include code into comments. You can update the question with additional information.

Comment: Also, you probably want to `rm` the local file, not the remote one, right?

Comment: No. Is everything that I run behind `bin/bash <<EOF` done on the remote side? I think so. Then it would be correct to `rm` the remote file as I have copied this one to my local machine and do not need it anymore on the remote server.

Comment: Ah, you're talking about the code in the comment, I was talking about the original one in the question. I've already commented on the one in the comment.

Comment: For `${var}` vs `$var`, see [What is the difference between `${var}`, `“$var”`, and `“${var}”` in the Bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135451/what-is-the-difference-between-var-var-and-var-in-the-bash-shell)

Answer (score 0):

Use `rsync` with `--remove-source-files`.

```
rsync --remove-source-files "${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST}:$FOLDERPATH_REMOTE.tar.gz" \
                            "$FOLDERPATH_LOCAL.tar.gz"
```

In response to your other questions, you need to use `${VAR}` when putting the variable name in the middle of a word-- `-` and `.` are fine separators, but `_` is not.

```
echo $var.txt      # same as ${var}.txt
echo $var-2020.txt # same as ${var}-2020.txt
echo $var_2020.txt # same as ${var_2020}.txt
```

You should also use `[ "$?" -eq 0 ]` to avoid the `[[ not found` error- you haven't mentioned your OS, but you appear not to have bash as /bin/sh.  None of this is necessary if you use `rsync` of course.